# .net core and SAML 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

Our University has migrated to a SAML based authentication/authorization method using Shibboleth.

I have been researching for at least a day on how to use SAML with .net core web applications.  I can't use Identity server 4 because it is for OaTH/Open ID.  I found some documentation on [msdn](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/SAML-2-Shibboleth-Example-0ce29093) which points to a commercial implementation. I came across this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35293504/873487) answer from a year ago saying Kentor may support it in the future but couldn't find anything on the github page about support for .net core or a .net core sample web app.  As of January it was still planned but no date.

The University has the identity provider running.  What I don't understand is the following:

1. How do I set my web application to use that identity provider?
2. How do I check if that identity provider has already been authenticated for another application, so SSO use?

Also, any sample applications that use SAML without commercial plugins would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

ITfoxtec has a ASP.NET MVC Core 1.0 SAML2 plugin, but it requires the .NET Full Framework, and won't run on linux. There's some missing APIs that are preventing full .NET Core support right now for SAML2 (around Crypto XML namespace). https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2

Not exactly what you're looking for I know, but it's an interim solution until probably .NET Standard 2.0, which will probably bring the missing API's to .NET Core.

Answer (score 1):

ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 support .NET Core 2.1 (without the .NET Framework) from version 3.0.0. Project: https://itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2

ITfoxtec Identity Saml2 MVC Core support ASP.NET MVC Core 2.1. NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.MvcCore/