# What options are there when we have a SAML 2.0 environment and want to apply it towards .Net Core?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, authorization, saml

I've been seeing that there is no support for SAML in .Net Core.  Due to existing environment restrictions, we need to leave the SAML process in place.  Other developers are pushing new development in .Net Core.  My response would be to develop in the regular .Net framework where we have a working model with SAML.

To entertain the masses, what would be viable options to get .Net Core to be secured by a SAML login process, with whatever it takes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Core SAML authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292397/asp-net-core-saml-authentication)

Comment: Did u concidered IdentityServer as an authentication proxy to map SAML and openid/connect ?