# ASP.Net Core - Turn SAML assertion into ClaimsPrincipal

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, saml, saml-2.0, kentor-authservices

There's a [question about using SAML in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292397/asp-net-core-saml-authentication), but I need additional help.

The only answer there mentions Kentor.AuthServices, but I don't understand how to use it. Everything I find on this or other SAML libraries, the documentation, blog posts, and sample applications are all about contacting some external authentication service and handling login and logout.

But I don't need any of that. The setup I'm working with does that in an edge-facing firewall application, and login/logout requests never reach my application. All I get is a SAML token in a cookie, which I need to validate and turn into a ClaimsPrincipal. I can't (the deployment network setup is insanely paranoid) and don't want to contact any identity provider.

Currently I've written a piece of middleware that takes the cookie, parses it, and parses out the parts I need for the claims principal. But I don't do any validation, either of the XML signature or of the SAML validity (valid time attributes etc). With .Net Core 2.0 Preview 2 I can do the XML signature validation, but I'm still stuck on doing the SAML validation. Is there a library that simply validates SAML constraints and does nothing else (or, at least, where I can ignore everything else)? I believe Kentor or ITfoxtec or elerch's SAML2.Core must contain such functionality, but I can't figure out where it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with SecurityTokenHandlerCollection class in System.IdentityModel.Tokens
I hope this code will help you.

```
 public Saml2SecurityToken DeserializeSAMLResponse(string samlResponse)
    {
        //Deserializing saml response

        Saml2SecurityToken token;
        using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(samlResponse)))
        {
            reader.ReadToFollowing("Assertion", Infrastructure.Enumerations.StringEnum.GetStringValue(SAMLProtocoles.SAML_20_ASSERTION));
            // Deserialize the token so that data can be taken from it and plugged into the RSTR
            SecurityTokenHandlerCollection tokenHandlerCollection = SecurityTokenHandlerCollection.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollection();
            token = (Saml2SecurityToken)tokenHandlerCollection.ReadToken(reader.ReadSubtree());
        }

        //Deserializing successful
        return token;
    }
```

It will internally validate the SAML and parse it in Saml2SecurityToken
After you get the token you can the the Users Credentials like this

```
  public User ReadSamlResponse(string samlResponse, string profileName, bool isSAMLProfile = true)
    {
        User User = new User();
        var DecodedSamlResponse = Convert.FromBase64String(samlResponse);
        string ResponseDecoded = coding.UTF8.GetString(DecodedSamlResponse);

            Saml2SecurityToken Token = _samlAuthenticationService.DeserializeSAMLResponse(ResponseDecoded);
            if ()// apply condition here if you need to validate signature
            {
                if (!_samlAuthenticationService.ValidateSamlToken(ResponseDecoded, AuthenticationConnector, isSAMLProfile))
                    throw new Exception("Signature is invalid");
            }

            User = GetUserFromToken(Token);
            return User;
        }
```

And to get User for Security Token you can do this

```
 public User GetUserFromToken(Saml2SecurityToken Token)
    {
        //Get user information from the token started
        User User = new User();
        if (Token != null)
        {
            if (Token.Assertion.Subject.NameId != null && (Token.Assertion.Subject.NameId.Format == null || Token.Assertion.Subject.NameId.Format.OriginalString == "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress"))
                User.EmailAddress = Token.Assertion.Subject.NameId.Value;
            foreach (var Statement in Token.Assertion.Statements)
            {
                var AttributeStatement = Statement as Saml2AttributeStatement;
                var AuthenticationStatement = Statement as Saml2AuthenticationStatement;
                if (AttributeStatement != null)
                    foreach (var Saml2Attribute in AttributeStatement.Attributes)
                    {
                        if (Saml2Attribute.Name.Equals("mail") || Saml2Attribute.Name.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"))
                            User.EmailAddress = Saml2Attribute.Values[0];
                        if (Saml2Attribute.Name.Equals("uid") || Saml2Attribute.Name.Equals("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"))
                            User.Name = Saml2Attribute.Values[0];
                        if (Saml2Attribute.Name.Equals("phone"))
                            User.MobileNumber = Saml2Attribute.Values[0];
                        if (Saml2Attribute.Name.Equals("title"))
                            User.JobTitle = Saml2Attribute.Values[0];
                        if (Saml2Attribute.Name.Equals("company"))
                            User.CompanyName = Saml2Attribute.Values[0];
                    }
                if (AuthenticationStatement != null)
                {
                    User.SAMLSessionIndex = AuthenticationStatement.SessionIndex;
                }
            }
        }
        //Successfully parsed user credentials
        return User;
    }
```

Comment: System.IdentityModel is not supported in .net core yet

Comment: I think then you should parse the SAML Assertion manually to calims principles

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/11/19/oauth2-with-saml2.html

This blog of scott has explained it in simple way.