# SAML Authentication with Azure AAD B2C and DotNetCore

Tags: .net-core, saml, azure-ad-b2c

Guys I have found some links regarding SAML Authentication with AAD but when i go for SAML Authentication with AAD B2C and DotNet Core I didnt find any article on this.

I found that it can be implemented through Custom Policies but how? Didnt find any implementation.

Gone through the links below but havent worked out.

https://cmatskas.com/asp-net-core-saml-authentication-with-azure-ad/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-technical-profile.

It will be nice of you if anyone can help me out with any guidance or any solution so that we can implement SAML with AAD B2C and Dot NetCore?

Comment: Hi @Nikhil. Can I ask why you are planning for SAML when, by default, both .NET Core and Azure AD B2C support OpenID Connect?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Thanks for you suggestion but we having a limitation to configure SSO using SAML only. If you can help regarding SAML with AAD B2C and Core will be appreciable.

Comment: No problems, @Nikhil, please consider my below answer. Note that [the above link](https://cmatskas.com/asp-net-core-saml-authentication-with-azure-ad/) is referring to the WS-Federation protocol, not SAML. Azure AD B2C has support (in preview) for SAML but it doesn't support WS-Federation.

Comment: Hi @Nikhil. Did either of the below answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

[SAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/saml-technical-profile) in B2C using custom policies.

B2C [sample code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnetcore-webapp) for a web application using .NET Core.

Custom policies are complex - [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/tips-and-tricks-for-working-with-custom-policies-in-azure-ad-b2c-eb63b508a075) may help you plus there is a link to a training course at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For information about creating a SAML Relying Party policy for Azure AD B2C, see [this sample policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/saml-sp).

(Note that, as at 11 July 2019, support for a SAML Relying Party policy is a preview feature.)

Refer to answers for [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35292397/asp-net-core-saml-authentication) for ASP.NET Core authentication middleware that is available for SAML.